# how to remove case sensitivity in ASP.Net Query Extender data field search?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols, search-box, query-extender

I applied a query extender to my text box for three fields. Its Working but it is case sensitive. e.g. if a username field is having a name "AWAIS" and i search for "awais" , it does not search and vice virsa. How can i remove sensitivity ?

My Code is

```
    <td>
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="BookStore.Bussines.Entities.BookStoreEntities"
                    OnSelecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting">
                </asp:LinqDataSource>
                <asp:QueryExtender ID="qeSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinqDataSource1">
                    <asp:SearchExpression DataFields="DISTRIBUTOR_NAME,DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,DISTRIBUTOR_URL" SearchType="Contains">
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchDistributor" />
                    </asp:SearchExpression>
                </asp:QueryExtender>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd537671%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Case sensitivity in the search expression depends on the LINQ provider that you specify in the QueryExtender control.
>
> If the LINQ provider that you use in the QueryExtender control supports case sensitivity, you can use the [ComparisonType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.expressions.searchexpression.comparisontype(v=vs.110).aspx) property to enable or ignore case sensitivity.

**Another Possibility - Database Collation**

Perhaps your database is set up to be case sensitive. Some links if you're using SQL Server.

[SQL Server Collation Description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[Description of Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd537671%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this control you would see how case sensitivity is handled:

> Case sensitivity in the search expression depends on the LINQ provider that you specify in the QueryExtender control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set `SearchExpression.ComparisonType` to `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

```
<asp:SearchExpression DataFields="DISTRIBUTOR_NAME,DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,DISTRIBUTOR_URL" SearchType="Contains" ComparisonType=StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchDistributor" />
                    </asp:SearchExpression>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.expressions.searchexpression.comparisontype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx